# rails routes optional parameters types by :id or :name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, testing, routes, custom-routes

Scenario:
I would like to have a url path where you could look someone up by an `:id` or `:name:`.
For `user/5` or `/user/tom` would all point to the same user

**routes.rb**

```
controller 'user' do  
    get 'user/:id'  
    get 'user/:name'  
end
```

**test/routes/user_routes.rb**

```
test "/user/:id" do  
  assert_routing "/user/5", :controller => "user", :action => "find_by_id", :id=>"5"  
end  

test "/user/:name" do  
  assert_routing "/user/tom", :controller => "user", :action => "find_by_name", :name=>"tom"  
end
```

I am not exactly sure if this is the right design decision with URL paths.
Looking for guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you are doing is going to work, because the routes you gave are ambiguous, because rails routes can't say that url like user/15 has name or id.

Of course there is a way to do this, by specifying regular expression. Since id will always be a number, we can have regular expression check for it

```
controller 'user' do  
    get 'user/:id', :id => /\d+/
    get 'user/:name', :name => /[A-Za-z][\w\s]+/
end
```

The above statements put a constraint of regular expression. In your controller you can check like

```
if params[:id]
# Get by id
else
# Get by name
```

You can also do this by passsing get parameters and handling it in controller in the same way.

Thanks

Comment: I think the feedback on being ambiguous is correct. I do like the solution you provided, but maybe I need to rethink my URL path designs.